# I want the circleMarkers to be top of the polygons, currently they are not clickable after the polygon added to map

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, jquery

I have used dynamic variables to store reference of the layers to make them off and on with html checkboxes in the menu bar.
I have used create pane to order the panes stack but that didn't worked.
I took some help from here with order of panes, http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/39/
[image: Below is the Image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var all_activities_id      = [];
    var project_filter_applied = '<?php echo json_encode($data['project_filter_applied']);?>' ;
    var geofilters             = '<?php echo json_encode($data['geofilters']);?>' ;
    var map;
    var boundry_layer;
    var check = 0;
    var features = null;
    var drawLayerSite = null;
    var baseLayers;
    var clicked_marker;
    var popup;
    var projects_details;
    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 7,
        fillColor: "black",
        color: "black",        
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };
    var baseLayers = {

    };
    var layers_variables_demo        = {};
    var layers_variables_demo_legend = {};
    var cities ;
    var markers;
    var markerList = [];
    var myRenderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5
    });
    var initialise = 0;
    var project_names = [];
    var overlays = {};
    var legend;
    var layers_variables           = {};
    var layers_variables_clusters  = {};
    var cat_ids;

    function initMap() {


       var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

    var streets     = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/light-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

        map = new L.map('map', {
            center: [30.3753, 69.3451],
            zoom: 6,
            layers: [streets],
            zoomControl: false
        });
         map.createPane("markers");
        map.createPane("polygons");
        // map.createPane("linesPane");


        L.control.zoom({
            position: 'bottomright'
        }).addTo(map); // console.log(map);


        baseLayers = {
            "Grayscale": grayscale,
            "Streets": streets
        };

        cat_ids  = '<?php echo json_encode($data['data_set_project_ids']);?>' 
        cat_ids  = jQuery.parseJSON(cat_ids);
        if(cat_ids.length > 0){
            setMap(cat_ids);
        }
    } // end initMap function

    var cat_id = 68;

    //Initializing HeatMap on Map
    function setHeatMap(){
        var other_data_sets_session = '<?php echo json_encode($data['other_data_sets_session']);?>';
        var popupContent ;
          $.ajax({
            url: '{!!route('heat-map-client-portal')!!}',
            data: {
                other_data_sets_session:other_data_sets_session,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               var geojson;
                if(data != 'false'){
                    jQuery.each(data, (index, item) => {
                        jQuery.each(item, (index1, item1) => {

                            var name = index+index1; 
                            if(index == 10026){

                                layers_variables_demo[name] = new L.geoJSON(item1, {                       
                                    style: styleHouseHold,
                                    onEachFeature: onEachFeatureHouseHold,
                                    pane: "polygons",
                                }).addTo(map);

                                    layers_variables_demo_legend[name] = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
                                    layers_variables_demo_legend[name].onAdd = function (map) {

                                        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                                        labels = ['<strong>HouseHold</strong>'],
                                            grades = [600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 2000]
                                            labels = [];
                                            div.innerHTML += '<strong>HouseHold</strong><br>';
                                        // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
                                        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                                            div.innerHTML +=
                                                '<i style="background:' + getColorHouseHold(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                                                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
                                        }

                                        return div;
                                    };
                                    layers_variables_demo_legend[name].addTo(map);
                            }
                            else if(index == 10027){                               
                                layers_variables_demo[name] = new L.geoJSON(item1, {                       
                                    style: style,
                                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                                    pane: "polygons",

                                }).addTo(map);

                                layers_variables_demo_legend[name] = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
                                    layers_variables_demo_legend[name].onAdd = function (map) {

                                        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                                            labels = ['<strong>Population</strong>'],
                                            grades = [1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, 6000 ,7000]
                                            labels = [];
                                            div.innerHTML += '<strong>Population</strong><br>';
                                        // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
                                        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                                            div.innerHTML +=
                                                '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                                                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
                                        }

                                        return div;
                                    };
                                    layers_variables_demo_legend[name].addTo(map);
                            }                                                                      
                        });
                    });
                   map.setView(new L.LatLng(24.9372,  67.0423), 14);
                }

                // console.log(data[10027]['Sindh']);
                // boundry_layer = new L.geoJSON(data[10027][0], {                       
                //     style: style,
                //     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                // }).addTo(map);                                 
            },           
        });

            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                popupContent = "<p> " +
                    'Province: '+feature.properties.Province + '<br>' + 'District: '+feature.properties.District +    '<br>'  +'Tehsil: '+feature.properties.Tehsil+ '<br>'  +
                    'City Code: '+ feature.properties.C_Code +  '<br>' + 'Charge Code: '+ feature.properties.Charge_Cod +   '<br>' + 'Circle Code: '+feature.properties.Circle_Cod+ '<br>' +  'Population: '+feature.properties.Population+ 
                    '<br>' + "</p>";

                layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                layer.on({             
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });                          
            }
            function onEachFeatureHouseHold(feature, layer) {                  
                popupContent = "<p> " +
                    'Province: '+feature.properties.Province + '<br>' + 'District: '+feature.properties.District +    '<br>'  +'Tehsil: '+feature.properties.Tehsil+ '<br>'  +
                    'City Code: '+ feature.properties.C_Code +  '<br>' + 'Charge Code: '+ feature.properties.Charge_Cod +   '<br>' + 'Circle Code: '+feature.properties.Circle_Cod+ '<br>' +  'HouseHold: '+feature.properties.House_Hold+ 
                    '<br>' + "</p>";

                layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                layer.on({             
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });                          
            }
            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 7000  ? '#FF4416' :
                       d > 6000  ? '#FF9216' :
                       d > 5000  ? '#FF167C' :               
                       d > 4000  ? '#BD0026' :
                       d > 3500  ? '#E31A1C' :
                       d > 3000  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                       d > 2000  ? '#FD8D3C' :
                       d > 1500   ? '#FEB24C' :
                       d > 1000   ? '#FED976' :
                                  '#FFEDA0';
            }

            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Population),
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                };
            }

             function getColorHouseHold(d) {
                return d > 1200  ? '#996600' :
                       d > 1150  ? '#ffcc00' :
                       d > 1100  ? '#ffcc00' :
                       d > 1050  ? '#FF9216' :
                       d > 1000  ? '#FF167C' :               
                       d > 950  ? '#BD0026' :
                       d > 900  ? '#E31A1C' :
                       d > 850  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                       d > 800  ? '#FD8D3C' :
                       d > 750   ? '#FEB24C' :
                       d > 700   ? '#FED976' :
                       d > 650   ? '#d6d6c2' :
                       d > 600   ? '#999966' :
                                  '#FFEDA0';
            }
            function styleHouseHold(feature) {
                return {
                    fillColor: getColorHouseHold(feature.properties.House_Hold),
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                };
            }         
    }

    //Initializing Projects Points on Map
    function setMap(cat_ids) {    

        $.ajax({
            url: '{!!route('all-outlets-map-client-portal')!!}',
            data: {
                cat_ids: cat_ids, project_filter_applied:project_filter_applied, geofilters:geofilters
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                locations = data;
                ids       = data.project_ids;
                // console.log(ids); 
                initialise = 1;                           
                populate(cat_ids); 
                all_activities_id.push(locations);         
            }
        });

        function populate(cat_ids) {
            if(initialise == 1){
                // // console.log('here');
                // markers.clearLayers();
                // // map.removeLayer(markers)
                // for(i=0;i<markerList.length;i++) {
                //     map.removeLayer(markerList[i]);
                // }
            }
            $.each(cat_ids, function( index, value ){                 
                cities = '';              
                layers_variables[value]           = L.layerGroup();
                layers_variables_clusters[value]  = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
                    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
                    disableClusteringAtZoom: 16
                });

                map.addLayer(layers_variables_clusters[value]);  
                var color = getRandomColor();

                for (var i = 0; i < locations[value].length; i++) {               
                    var id  = locations[value][i].id;
                    var lat = locations[value][i].latitude;
                    var lng = locations[value][i].longitude;

                    var marker = new L.circleMarker(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), {
                        radius: 6,
                        pane: "markers",
                        fillColor: color,
                        color: color,        
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        renderer: myRenderer
                    }).addTo(layers_variables[value]);

                    // map.addLayer(marker);
                    marker.on('click', onClick_Marker)
                    // Attach the corresponding JSON data to your marker:
                    marker.id     = id;
                    marker.cat_id = value;
                    marker.color  = color;
                    markerList.push(marker);
                    layers_variables_clusters[value].addLayer(marker);
                } //end for loop        
                 // console.log(cities);

                $('.mb-2').each(function() {
                     var id = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('data-name');  
                     if(id == value){
                        $(this).find('.superawesome').css("background-color", color);
                     }                      
                });
                // layers_variables[value] = cities;               
            });
        // console.log(all_activities_id);
        } //end Populate function
        // map.addLayer(markers); 
        if(initialise == 0){    
            L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);       
        }  
    } //end setupfunction

    function getRandomColor() {

        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    function onClick_Marker(e) {
        clicked_marker  = e.target;
        map.setView(e.latlng, 20);
        var activity_id = clicked_marker.id;
        var cat_id = clicked_marker.cat_id;
        var locations_one;
        clicked_marker.unbindPopup();

        // map.setView([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], 12);

        clicked_marker.setStyle({
            color: 'black',
            fillColor: '#DEBB56',
            radius: 10,        
        });

        popup = L.popup().setLatLng(clicked_marker.getLatLng()).setContent('Loading...').openOn(map);
        $.ajax({
            url: '{!!route('all-outlets-map-client-portal')!!}',
            data: {
                cat_id: cat_id,
                activity_id: activity_id
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: initializeOutletPopup
        });
    } //end onClick_Marker function

    function initializeOutletPopup(locations_one) {

        if ($('.single-item').hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
            // $('.single-item')[0].slick.refresh();
            // $('.single-item').slick('unslick');
             $('.single-item').slick('destroy');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < locations_one.length; i++) {
            var outlet   = locations_one[i]['outlet'];
            var a        = locations_one[i];
            var col_name = '';
            var outlet_header = '';
            var images_slider = '';
            var outlet_content = '';
            var lat_lng = '';

            jQuery('#masterdiv div').html('');

            outlet_header = '<h5 class="modal-title mb-1" id="exampleModalLabel">' +
                outlet.outlet_name +
                '</h5>' + '<p class="m-0">' +
                outlet.full_address +
                '</p>';

            jQuery.each(outlet, (index, item) => {
                var field_name;
                field_name = index.toString();
                // console.log(index);                      
                if (index == 'updated_at' || index == 'images' || index == 'id' || index == 'created_at' || index == 'full_address') {

                } else {
                    if (item == null) {
                        var index1 = index.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                        col_name = titleCase(index1);
                        var item1 = '';
                        outlet_content = outlet_content + '<li><label>' + col_name + '</label><span>' + item1 + '</span></li>';
                    } else {
                        var index1 = index.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                        col_name = titleCase(index1);
                        outlet_content = outlet_content + '<li><label>' + col_name + '</label><span>' + item + '</span></li>';
                    }
                }
                if (outlet.images.length) {
                    if (field_name != 'id' && field_name != 'created_at' && field_name != 'updated_at' && field_name != 'outlet_code' && outlet.images[0][field_name] != null && outlet.images[0][field_name] != undefined) {
                        var all_images = outlet.images[0][field_name].split(",");
                        for (var i = 0; i < all_images.length; i++) {
                            var image_name = all_images[i];
                            image_name = 'mobile_app/outlet_images/' + outlet.id + '/' + field_name + '/' + image_name;

                            images_slider = images_slider + '<div><img data-lazy="' + image_name + '" class="img-fluid m--marginless" alt="" style="width:100%; height:100%" /></div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }); // end jqueryEach loop

            if (images_slider == null) {

            } else {
                $('.images_slider').empty();
                $("#m_modal_1_2").find(".images_slider").append(images_slider);
            }

            lat_lng = '<p class="m-0">lat  ' + a.lat + '&nbsp; &nbsp; lon  ' + a.lng + '</p>';
            outlet_content = '<ul class="map_result_modal_list outlet_content">' + outlet_content + '</ul>';

        } //for loop end  

        $('.outlet_header').empty();
        $('.outlet_content').empty();
        $('.lat_lng').empty();

        $("#m_modal_1_2").find(".outlet_header").append(outlet_header);
        $("#m_modal_1_2").find(".outlet_content").append(outlet_content);
        $("#m_modal_1_2").find(".lat_lng").append(lat_lng);
        map.closePopup();      
        $('#m_modal_1_2').modal();
        // $("#m_modal_1_2").show();                          
        // L.popup().setLatLng(clicked_marker.getLatLng()).setContent(title).openOn(map);

    } //end nitializeOutletPopup Function

    function titleCase(str) {
        var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
            splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
        }
        return splitStr.join(' ');
    }

    $('#m_modal_1_2').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        clicked_marker.setStyle({
            radius: 6,
            fillColor: clicked_marker.color,
            color: clicked_marker.color,        
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        });
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Does [`bringToFront()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circlemarker-bringtofront) work?

Comment: Your code is not specifying the `z-index` of the map panes. Please re-read https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: @IvanSanchez thankyou, i was able to bring the points to front(clickable), **map.getPane('markers').style.zIndex = 750;
  map.getPane('polygons').style.zIndex = 350; **
with this the points are clickable but the popup for the polygon don't seems to be clickable. Im new to leaflet so I don't know much.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I can provide you the link if you say so that you view it directly.

Comment: See docs about map panes: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-pane. Popups are on separate pane with `z-index` value of 700. If you cover this with another pane with higher `z-index`, they might not work.

Comment: @TomazicM thankyou for briefing me onto z-index of these panes,
Actually I tried different z-index to make it work, but Im to able to completely understand how solve this issue,
Below is the working link of this.
[http://104.248.154.190/retailplatform/client-portal-demo?data_set_ids=%5B10026%2C68%5D&other_data_set_ids=%5B%22Sindh%22%2C10026%5D&ids%5B%5D=68]

Comment: If you found the solution, you might put it in an explained answer the help others with similar problems.

Comment: @TomazicM i didn't found yet, shared the link so can you view it and  if you could help me out with the z-index if it works.

Comment: I don't see any clickable item in the popup.

Comment: @TomazicM actually its not working , I shared the link so that Anyone could help me out how to make both points and polygon clickable.